# Eclipse Kepler won't open on OS X 10.9.1

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-mavericks

I installed Kepler on my fairly new mbp running 10.9.1. Initially this worked, but now when it won't open. Clicking on the docked icon shortcut will start eclipse, but the small loading bar gets to slightly past "loading workbench" then the whole app shuts down. Running in the terminal gives me this error:

```
Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55
```

I read that others were having Java issues with eclipse on mavericks but I'm not sure that is my case, especially since it was previously running. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this issue by deleting the .metadata folder, forcing eclipse to create a fresh one. Works great now.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Delete the **.metadata** directory will make Eclipse run again. 
You can find .metadata folder **at your workspace directory.**

### Consequences

1. All **IDE projects structure will be reset**. The projects data
   will be kept at the file system.
2. All **IDE configuration data will be reset**. You'll have to create it again.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I found that it was possible to be more surgical.  The issue in my case was in the .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench folder.  Clearing that, I lost my UI state, but all of the projects, SVN connections, etc... weren't lost.